# Delete A Particular Value When Using WorksheetFunction.Count

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to create a unique list of email addresses, I need to modify it a bit to delete the value `<UNASSIGNED>`. I am using this code to create a list of email addresses but some of the data does not have an email address assigned so the field has the text `<UNASSIGNED>`. I want to ignore this value.

```
'If not, add name, semi-colon and space to temporary name list
         If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & x), Range("C" & x)) < 2 Then
             namelist_tmp = namelist_tmp & Range("C" & x) & "; "
         End If
      Next
'Strip last semi-colon & space off of temp list
          namelist = Left(namelist_tmp, Len(namelist_tmp) - 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `CountIf` function call:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & x), "<>" & "<UNASSIGNED>") < 2 Then
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers but looks like my posting lost the text string I am trying to ignore. I am trying to ignore this text string '<UNASSIGNED>'. I think the editor on stackoverflow is interpreting the <> signs and removed the word UNASSIGNED

Comment: you mean some cells contain the string `<UNASSIGNED>`?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean :-)

Comment: I have amended the answer. Check whether that works for you

Comment: Did Not work; I added a missing parenthesis but my result did not add the email addresses but only added <UNASSIGNED>.  I had to add single quotes because the VBA editor was doing something funky because the <> surrounding the word UNASSIGNED This is the code I used If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & x), "<>" & "'<UNASSIGNED>'") < 2 Then

Comment: OK that's fine. I have amended the answer. I am not sure why you needed the single quotes, though

Comment: I fixed it by making the IF statements 2 separate lines.   If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & x), "<>" & "<UNASSIGNED>") Then
 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & x), Range("C" & x)) < 2 Then